# Running python scripts causes BSOD seemingly at random

Tags: python, windows-7, python-3.2

I am working with Python 3.2 on an HP desktop running Windows 7. For awhile I have had issues with Python crashing my system, causing a blue screen of death, and I can't find any pattern in when it happens.

It has happened before when I closed out of the Python Shell, but mainly it happens when I initiate a run of the program out of IDLE.

It has also happened upon running several different programs, including larger applications using about a dozen modules, as well as on simple 6-liner test code with no imports.

There have even been times when I have been running a tkinter GUI several times in a row changing nothing but label formatting inbetween runs, and it will work fine for five or six times in a row, then suddenly bam: BSOD.

I've looked through the python docs a little but don't see anything about a bug that may be causing this. I know I haven't given much to go off of, but any ideas for what might be happening would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**
The following is from the bugcheck analysis of dump file created when this happens.

```
CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4)
A process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been
terminated.
Several processes and threads are necessary for the operation of the
system; when they are terminated (for any reason), the system can no
longer function.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000003, Process
Arg2: 8725ed40, Terminating object
Arg3: 8725eeac, Process image file name
Arg4: 82e11ca0, Explanatory message (ascii)

Debugging Details:
------------------

----- ETW minidump data unavailable-----

PROCESS_OBJECT: 8725ed40
IMAGE_NAME:  mfehidk.sys
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  50296571
MODULE_NAME: mfehidk
FAULTING_MODULE: 00000000 
PROCESS_NAME:  pythonw.exe
BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF4_pythonw.exe
CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT
CURRENT_IRQL:  0
ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) x86fre
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 82ef3edb to 82cf118c
```

I don't know enough about the system for this to mean much to me, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Have you got a screenshot of this bsod?

Comment: Not currently, if it happens again I will try to get one.

Comment: When you get it see the reason(there is usually an explanation , a small message) try to search for this error in Microsoft or any other site :) Hope you get is solved quickly

Comment: Which STOP Code do you get? Analyze the dmp with Windbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: f4 (Critical Object Termination). I've updated the question to provide more info based on this.